# Get variable values from the DOM and use them as parameters in a webhook

Tags: javascript, jquery, webhooks, webflow

I'm very new to JS and trying to work around a limitation in Webflow. I want to get some values from the webpage, and use those as parameters in a webhook.

The page structure could look something like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="job_ID" class="hidden">123job</div>
  <div id="member_ID" class="hidden">123member</div>
  <a href="webhook.link" class="button">link</a>
</body>
```

I want to replace `webhook.link` with something like `https://hook.integromat.com/XXXXX?member=123member&job=123job`

I've been reading up about `document.getElementById` and `document.createElement`, but I'm honestly in way over my head.
How do I use the *job_ID* and *member_ID* values from the page to use in a webhook?

---

*Bonus Question*

Also, is there a way to set it up so that clicking the button triggers the webhook instead of visiting the webhook URL?

Comment: You can write your js and append it to your html but you have to export it first. Then you can edit it. 

You can give functions to button so it executes this function when you click. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

You can get your information inside the div like in here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="job_ID" class="hidden">123job</div>
  <div id="member_ID" class="hidden">123member</div>
  <a href="webhook.link" class="button">link</a>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
let button = document.querySelector('.button'); 
button.addEventListener('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.target.href = getHref();
});
function getHref(){
    let jobID = document.querySelector("#job_ID").innerHTML;
    let memberID = document.querySelector("#member_ID").innerHTML;
    return `https://hook.integromat.com/XXXXX?member=${memberID}&job=${jobID}`;
}
```

Whenever you want to access a DOM element, you will need to wait for the window to load or javascript will not find the DOM elements.  So, start your javascript inside the window load event.

The querySelector method of the document object is more efficent at selecting elements (in my opinion).  It is formatted as:

```
document.querySelector('tagName'); //this will get an element by tag
document.querySelector('p');

document.querySelector('.className'); //Starting the string with a period will select an element by class.
document.querySelector('.output');

document.querySelector('#elementID'); //Starting the string with a # will get an element by it's ID attribute
document.querySelector('#job_ID');
```

Using querySelector will only return the FIRST element that it finds matching your selector (the stuff inside the parenthesis).  If you need to select more than one element, use querySelectorAll

```
document.querySelectorAll('.hidden'); //will get all elements with class=hidden
```

In the button.addEventListener function above, you'll see the command

```
event.preventDefault();
```

This prevents the default action of an event from occurring, such as, an anchor tag redirecting to another page.  Instead, you'll place the code for whatever you want your button to do right after the preventDefault statement.

Good Luck with your project!